# What is the inverse function of $x^2$ when $x$ is negative?

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Since it is an injective and surjective function therefore it's inverse must exist.

NB:
I know that the inverse function of $x^2$ when $x$ is positive is square root function.

Comment: Note that in isolation, "$x^{2}$", or even "$f(x) = x^{2}$", is not a function: It's crucial to specify the domain and target (codomain) explicitly. Before you can say "[the function] is injective and surjective" you have to settle on these details (as the two existing answers are careful to do). (The implicit convention for $f(x) = x^{2}$ in precalculus is to take the domain and target to be $\mathbf{R}$, the set of real  numbers. Context shows that's not the intent here.)

Answer (score 2):

The inverse is given by $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ where $x \mapsto -\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 2):

The inverse of $(-\infty,0]\to [0,\infty)$, $x\mapsto  x^2$ is the function $[0,\infty)\to(-\infty,0]$, $x\mapsto -\sqrt x$.